# Understanding the proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{1/n}=1$ ($x>0$) in Tao's Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

I was reading sequences in Terence Tao Analysis book and I came across the question:

> Prove that $\forall x>0$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x^{1/n}=1$

In the **hint** it says that

> ... you may need to treat the cases $x\geq1$ and $x<1$ separately. You might wish to use Lemma 6.5.2 to prove the preliminary result that $\forall\epsilon>0$ and every real number $M>0$, $\exists$ an $n$ such that $M^{1/n}\leq1+\epsilon$.
>
> **Lemma 6.5.2 :** Let $x$ be a real number. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$ exists and is equal to $0$ when $|x|<1$, exists and is equal to $1$ when $x=1$, and diverges when $x=-1$ or when $|x|>1$.

How does the above Lemma 6.5.2 help in proving the preliminary result given in the hint?
And how does this preliminary result in turn help to prove our final result?

Comment: In your statement of Lemma 6.5.2 don't you mean $x^n$ rather than $x^{1/n}$?

Comment: Does it really say $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ in Lemma 6.5.2? I think it should be $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^n$$ instead.

Comment: Sorry guys. I have corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that you know the proof for lemma 6.5.2.

Assume on the contrary that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $M^{1/n} > 1 + \epsilon$ so that $(1 + \epsilon)^{n} < M$ for all $n$. Now $x = 1 + \epsilon > 1$ and hence $x^{n}$ diverges to $\infty$ and this contradicts that $x^{n} = (1 + \epsilon)^{n} < M$. Therefore for any $M > 0$ and any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a positive integer $n$ such that $M^{1/n} < 1 + \epsilon$. This establishes the preliminary result in the hint.

---

Now we consider the limit of $x^{1/n}$ when $n \to \infty$. If $x = 1$ then the limit is obviously $1$. Now suppose that $x > 1$. Then clearly $x^{1/n} > 1$ for all $n$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. By preliminary result in last paragraph we know that there is a positive integer $m$ such that $x^{1/m} < 1 + \epsilon$. Note that $x > 1$ and hence if $n > m$ then $x^{1/n} < x^{1/m} < 1 + \epsilon$. It follows that for all values of $n \geq m$ we have $$1 - \epsilon < 1 < x^{1/n} < 1 + \epsilon$$ It is now clear (from definition of limit) that $x^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

For $0 < x < 1$ let us put $y = 1/x$ so that $y > 1$. Hence $y^{1/n} \to 1$ and $x^{1/n} = 1/y^{1/n} \to 1/1 = 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Thus we see that for $x > 0$ we have $x^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach:

First we'll show that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1$$ using the squeeze theorem.

For $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $1\leq\sqrt[n]{n}$. For $n\geq 2$ we can use the binomial theorem to get: $$n=\left(\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^n =[1+\left(\sqrt[n]n-1\right)]^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom nk \left(\sqrt[n]n-1\right)^k\geq \binom n2 \left(\sqrt[n]n-1\right)^2.$$ Thus we have $$ \left(\sqrt[n]n-1\right)^2\leq \frac n{\binom n2}=\frac 2{n-1}.$$ As both sides of the equation are strictly positive we can take the root which yields $$\sqrt[n]n-1\leq \sqrt {\frac 2{n-1}} \Leftrightarrow \sqrt[n]n\leq 1+\sqrt{\frac 2{n-1}}.$$ As $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}=1$ we can now use the squeeze theorem to get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1$.

Now: for $x>1$ there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ with $n\geq x$. This yields $$1\leq \sqrt[n]{x}\leq\sqrt[n]{n}$$ and we again apply the squeeze theorem.

For $0<x<1$ we have $\frac{1}{x}>1$ and thus we get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{x}}=1$ which also yields $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{x}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $0 < x < 1$, then put $y = \dfrac{1}{x}$, we can consider only the case $x > 1$. By AM-GM inequality: $1 \leq \sqrt[n]{x}=\sqrt[n]{1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdots \sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{x}}\leq \dfrac{(n-2)+2\sqrt{x}}{n}=1+\dfrac{2(\sqrt{x}-1)}{n}$.Next apply squeeze theorem to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Other simplistic approaches $$A=x^{1/n}$$ $$\log(A)=\frac 1n \log(x)$$ So, $\log(A)\to 0$ and $A\to 1$.

Similarly, $$A=x^{1/n}=e^{\frac  {\log(x)} n}\to e^0=1$$

Answer (score 0):

As $\dfrac1{x^{1/n}}=\left(\dfrac1x\right)^{1/n}$, it suffices to establish the property for $x>1$.

It is enough to say
$$x^{1/n}-1=(x^{1/n}-1)\frac{x-1}{(x^{1/n})^n-1}=\frac{x-1}{(x^{1/n})^{n-1}+(x^{1/n})^{n-2}+\cdots1}<\frac{x-1}n.$$