# How would you show that for every $ε>0$ and every real number $M>0$ there exists some positive integer $n$ such that $M^{\frac{1}{n}}\le 1+ε$

Tags: limits, inequality

For some context, according to Tao (Analysis I/Exercise 6.5.3.) this can be shown via Lemma 6.5.2, which he states as: let $x$ be a real number. Then the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}x^n$ exists and is equal to zero when $|x|<1$, exists and is equal to $1$ when $x=1$, and diverges when $x=-1$ or when $|x|>1$.

From there I logically thought (after I chose the numbers $ε>0$ and $M>0$ to be arbitrary) to use the limit definition of the above limit and then assume by way of contradiction that $M^{\frac{1}{n}}\gt 1+ε$ for all positive integers $n\ge 1$. So I considered the cases $M<1$ or $M\gt 1$ (I omit the case when $M=1$ since it's trivial) due to trichotomy.

From there, I firstly assumed $M$ to be $\lt 1$. Thus, by the above lemma we have the $\lim_{n\to \infty}M^n=0$, and so by the definition of the limit (for sequences) we can find some $N\ge 1$ such that $|M^n-0|<ε$ for all $n\ge N$. Which means that $$M^n<ε=(ε+1)-1<Μ^{\frac{1}{n}}-1<0$$ for all $n\ge N$, a contradiction, since $0<M<1$. On the other hand, in the case that $M>1$ we have that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{1}{M})^n=0$, and so this means that we can find some $N\ge1$ such that $|(\frac{1}{M})^n-0|<ε$ for all $n\ge N$. Thus we have that $$M^{-n}<M^{\frac{1}{n}}-1.$$But,
I'm left stumped and unable to reach a contradiction from this point on. I think the problem is that I didn't choose the right $"ε"$ or perhaps I should have made a better application of the given lemma.

Could someone hint me in the right direction as to how I could finish this proof?

**NOTE**

Also, I saw that the exact question was answered about 8 years ago ([Understanding the proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{1/n}=1$ ($x>0$) in Tao's Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351067/understanding-the-proof-that-lim-n-to-inftyx1-n-1-x0-in-taos-analy)), but I'm not satisfied by those justifications, since I prefer to stick with the stuff I come up with instead of copying from other people's work.

Comment: Can you prove that there is some $n$ such that $M\leq(1+\varepsilon)^n$?

Answer (score 2):

First we assume that the following are known:

$(1)$
$$a \gt b \gt 0 \implies a^n \gt b^n \gt 0 .  $$

$(2)$
An increasing sequence that is bounded above converges.  (Proposition 6.3.8 of Tao's Analysis I)

Next we prove the statement by contradiction.

Assume that the statement is not true.

i.e.  $ \exists \varepsilon \gt 0, M \gt 0$ s.t.  $$M^{\frac{1}{n}} \gt 1+\varepsilon \gt 0  \qquad  \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$$

By $(1)$, we have
$$ M \gt (1+\varepsilon)^n \gt 0 \qquad  \forall n \in \Bbb{N}  \tag{3}$$

Note that $\{(1+\varepsilon)^n \}$ is an increasing sequence.

$(3) \implies  \{(1+\varepsilon)^n \}$  is bounded above by $M$.

By $(2)$, $\{(1+\varepsilon)^n \}$ converges.

But $1+\varepsilon \gt 0 \implies \{(1+\varepsilon)^n \}$ diverges by Lemma 6.5.2.

Hence we obtain a contradiction.

Comment: The difficulty of the problem lies on the fact that one has to follow Tao's line of reasoning.

Comment: This is fine, but there is no need to proceed by contradiction.

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon I don't know how to prove directly. Would you show me how? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you managed to resolve it yet since the post was 20 days ago. I got stuck on the exact same problem today and i think I managed to solve it the way Tao intended, i think and by Li Kwok Keung is the most sensical but it does involve an extra albeit simple step of showing that $(1+\epsilon)^n$ is not only divergent but also unbounded. $(-1,1,-1,..)$ is divergent but not bounded for e.g. To show the result using lemma 6.5.2 and nothing else:

For any $\epsilon>0$, we have that $\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}<1$ and thus by lemma 6.5.2, the sequence $((\frac{1}{1+\epsilon})^n)$ will converge to $0$. Thus, it’s clear that there must exists $N$ st $(\frac{1}{1+\epsilon})^N<1/M$. Do some algebra here and you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the book but...

It is likely that to solve this exercise you have to use the logic inside the proof of Lemma 6.5.2 and to even slightly expand the exposition on your own.

You need to make sense of

$$ \text{IF } x \gt 1 \text{ THEN } \lim_{n\to \infty}x^n = +\infty $$

If Tao has covered the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) and the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) there is at least one way to handle this.